# How do I regression test serial comms?

Tags: serial-port, automated-tests, regression-testing

I'm working on code that communicates via serial port between different languages and different platforms, and I'd like a single test mechanism I can use that'll hook up to a serial port and then run a series of scripted conversations (send "this", wait for "that", pause 2s, wait for "that" again etc). Messages are binary. I could write something, but there must already be something out there for this that's had decades to mature, so not only would I be re-inventing the wheel but I'd probably be making it triangular. Does anyone know of such a thing? Can be either Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m not sure to understand your question... If what you are developing is a propietary (your own) serial protocol to execute some tasks from different platforms (with different programming languages), all talking your protocol, and what you want to do is to plug a serial cable from/to PC-device and send from the PC serial commands of your protocol to the device (could be another PC) to test your software, yes, there are plenty of software to send serial data:

With some limitations on the free versión:
http://www.commfront.com/commfront-downloads.htm

A full free software from Extron (you can send a script file):
http://www.extron.com/product/software.aspx?id=dataviewer&s=5

There are many more, specially if want to waste your money, but those are the ones i´ve worked with for some years and works great.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's what I want to do, but with clear pass/fail indication, the ability to use high numbered serial ports and the ability to ignore some replies to test error recovery/resending. Those two don't do what I want, but searching on their names led me to a list someone made of many of them that I'm now working through.